# Grouping by date range in a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with data as:

```
ID    Action    Date
1     Action1   2014-01-20
2     Action1   2014-01-22
3     Action1   2014-01-28
4     Action2   2014-01-20
5     Action2   2014-01-22
6     Action2   2014-01-28
```

I need to group by Date, grouping with 3 days of difference:

```
Action       Count
Action1      2
Action2      2
```

If a record is grouped with a previous record, it won't be in another group:

```
ID    Action    Date
1     Action1   2014-01-20
2     Action1   2014-01-23
3     Action1   2014-01-24

Action       Count
Action1      2
```

My solution:

```
SELECT T1.Action, DATEDIFF(DAY,T1.Date,T2.Date) as Count
FROM Table T1
JOIN Table T2 ON T1.Action=T2.Action
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,T1.Date,T2.Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
GROUP BY T1.Action,T1.Date,T2.Date
```

Is this a correct solution?

Comment: So, if there is a difference of more than 3 days between 2 consecutive rows, then that count should count as a group change, right?

Comment: The rows do not have to be consecutive rows. And yes, different groups.

Comment: Your edit actually confuses more than clarifies. What if there are 12 days, one after the other, will that be 1 group? Or 4?

Answer (score 7):

In SQL-Server 2012 version, looks straightforward with the `LAG()` function:

```
SELECT
    Action,
    Number = COUNT(*) 
FROM
    ( SELECT 
          Action, 
          Diff = DATEDIFF(day, LAG(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Action ORDER BY Date), Date)  
      FROM
          a
    ) AS t
WHERE 
    Diff > 3 OR Diff IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    Action ;
```

This should work, even in 2008 version:

```
SELECT
    Action,
    Number = COUNT(*) 
FROM
    a
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
    ( SELECT *
      FROM a AS b
      WHERE b.Action = a.Action
        AND ( (b.Date >= DATEADD(day, -3, a.Date) AND b.Date < a.Date)
           OR (b.Date = a.Date AND b.ID < a.ID)
            )
    ) 
GROUP BY 
    Action ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements need some clarification. For instance, assuming you have 3 dates separated by 1 day each, would that count as 2 groups with count 1 and 2 respectively, 2 and 1 or even 2 and 2?

An easy solution - albeit possibly not what you had in mind would be to mod3 the dates and group by that.